# datatable with twitter bootstrap 2 error in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I am trying to integrate Datatables + Bootstrap 2 as explained [here](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2).

Bundle all datatables also

```
 //Bundling JQuery datatables scripts together
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/DataTables").Include(
   "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/DT_bootstrap.js",
   "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"));

   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/css").Include(
   "~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/DT_bootstrap.css",
   "~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
   "~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"
                ));
```

and also rendered in `_layouts` page

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/js") 
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables") 
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/css")
```

If I run the page I am getting this error in `media/js/DT_bootstrap.js` file.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the scripts as a `ScriptBundle` - you've included them as a `StyleBundle`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/DataTables").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
                 "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/DT_bootstrap.js"
            ));
```

And place `jquery.dataTables.js` *before* `DT_bootstrap.js`.